# Using selected value from Drop down list html

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to get the value from a drop down menu (list) and use that value to create another drop down menu. I have a database in mysql, in that database is a list of departments and then each department has a list of courses. What I am trying to do is have a drop down list for the departments which I have already created and then use the value the user selected to make a drop down list for the courses.

EDIT: Updated code:

JavaScript dropmysql.js

```html
<!-- start: Container -->
<div class="container">

  <!-- start: Contact Form -->
  <div class="title">
    <h4>Contact Form</h4>
  </div>

  <!-- start: Contact Form -->
  <div id="contact-form">

    <form method="post" action="assets/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <fieldset>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <label for="name"><span>Name:</span>
          </label>
          <div class="input">
            <input tabindex="1" size="18" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">
          <label for="email"><span>Email:</span>
          </label>
          <div class="input">
            <input tabindex="2" size="25" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <label for="department"><span>Department:</span>
          </label>
          <select tabindex="3" type="text" name="Department">
            <?php while($dept=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<option value=\" ".$dept['dname']."\ ">".$dept[ 'dname']. "</option>"; } //<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown" id="course-container">
          <!-- SELECT WILL BE PLACED USING JAVASCRIPT -->
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
          <p>
            <label for="file"><span>Select file to upload:</span>
            </label>
            <input tabindex="8" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
          </p>
          <p>
            <input tabindex="3" type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" class="btn btn-succes btn-large">
          </p>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>

  </div>
  <!-- end: Contact Form -->
</div>
<!-- end: Container -->
<!-- start: Java Script -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/dropmysql.js"></script>
<script def src="js/custom.js"></script>
<!-- end: Java Script -->
```

PHP upload.php

```html
<?php
 include ("../config/database.php");

 if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
  $department = $_POST['department'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE dname = '{$department}'";

  while (mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      echo '<option value="{$value}>{$name}</option>"'; // Loop through the database again and echo them here
  }
 }
?>
```

PHP ddown.php:

```
<?php
include ("../config/database.php");

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    $department = $_POST['department'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE dname = '{$department}'";

    while (mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo '<option value="{$value}>{$name}</option>"'; // Loop through the database again and echo them here
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: @usermesam0023 No I dont mind, I'm unsure how to do it with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it will be helpful to add an id/class to the first select such as:

```
<select tabindex="3" type="text" name="Department" id="department">
    <option value="BSEN">BSEN</option>
    <option value="CPSC">CPSC</option>
    <option value="ENGG">ENGG</option>
</select>
```

You'll need to setup the 2nd dropdown list with empty options, or setup an empty div similar to this

```
<div id="course-container">
   <!-- SELECT WILL BE PLACED USING JAVASCRIPT -->
</div>
```

Then a javascript file similar to this could be used:

```
$(function() {
    var course_container = $("div#course-container");
    var data = {};

    $('select#department').change(function() {
        $(course_container).html("<select id=\"courses\"></select>");
        var courses = $("select#courses");
        var d = document.getElementById("department");
        data['department'] = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;

        $.ajax({
            url: "path/to/php/script.php",
            type: "post",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                $(courses).innerHTML = response;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then just a php script like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    $department = $_POST['department'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `DATABASE` WHERE `DEPARTMENT` = {$department}";

    while (mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo '<option value="{$value}>{$name}</option>"'; // Loop through the database again and echo them here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a couple questions. Thanks for the response though. For the javascript. I have the file in the folder before it, I use ../upload.php, would that work? 

And for the last php script, where abouts would I put that in my html file? I tried right before the </fieldset>.

Comment: The Ajax `url` can be set to any string so `url: "../upload.php"` should be acceptable. And the php can go on the head of your document, before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` if doing that, make sure to add the closing php tag -> `?>` else your php interpreter will think the whole file is php, and spit out major errors.

Comment: Ok, I did what you said but it doesnt seem to create another drop down list. I must be doing something wrong. I copied the js part into a .js file called dropmysql.js and changed url: "../upload.php". I put this at the very top of my php file <script src="js/dropmysql.js"></script>. Then within a <?php ?> I pasted ur last php script. I also put the empty div under my other drop down list. But nothing seems to happen even when I select a item from the drop down list.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your Javascript console?

Comment: @Anoml This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5uo70sn/) should do it, don't forget to add the `id="department"` into your first dropdown. Also, the last php script needs to be a separate file so the Ajax method can post data to it, and receive it back.

Comment: I dont believe so, I'm unsure how to check but no errors show up when im on the webpage. Just read you last comment, ill try new fixes

Comment: Using Safari/Chrome on Mac is `CMD-ALT-I`, Chrome on Windows is `CTRL-SHIFT-I`. Im not sure about Internet Explorer, or Firefox

Comment: Oh I never knew that, thats neat! Do I need to have the <script src="js/dropmysql.js"></script> in my main file? I put it into the separate php file for the seconds php script. Nothing happening still.

Comment: Could you update the files so I can have a better look?

Comment: Sorry it took so long but I finally updated it. Thanks for your consistent help!

Comment: Try the new Javascript, I should have it fixed

Comment: Unfortunately its still not working. How is it suppose to work, I am just scrolling down on the department drop down menu and clicking CPSC which has courses under it. Those should create a new drop down menu, correct?

Comment: Correct. The JSFiddle worked when I tried it aside from it populating the ite, s.

Comment: Can you send me your jsfiddle link please?

Comment: Thanks for the jfiddle, seems like I screwed something up in the php part. It looked like the exact same but when I copied yours from jfiddle it worked, I must have missed in closing something.

Comment: Hey, I am receiving a error with the java script now. The error I receive is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" which corresponds to this line: "data['department'] = $(this).options[$(this).selectedIndex].value;"

Comment: @anoml I fixed the Javascript code, I forgot to fix that when making the Fiddle

Comment: Thanks, slowly debugging haha! It doesn't show any errors now but there is no courses in the drop down list. Its just a empty drop down list. Not sure why, being trying to fiddle with it but cant figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a select element that looks like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
     <input type="hidden" id="depthidden" name="depthidden">
     <select tabindex="3" id="Department">
        <option value="BSEN">BSEN</option>
        <option value="CPSC">CPSC</option>
        <option value="ENGG">ENGG</option>
      </select>
```

Run this code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    var d = document.getElementById("Department");
    document.getElementsById('depthidden').Value = d.options[d.selectedIndex].value;
```

The above is just a JS demo to help you.

The php section:

```
$dname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['depthidden']);
while($dept= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
    if($dname==$dept[dname])
       echo "<option value = '".$dept[dname]."' selected>".$dept[dname]."</option>";
    else
       echo "<option value = '".$dept[dname]."'>".$dept[dname]."</option>"; 
 }
```

The $dname is the dept name to be populated. Otherwise, remove the if and keep the else part.

Comment: How do I use the dept variable to make another drop down list? I need to make a query in php. Something like:
$coursequery = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE dname='".var dept."'";

where var dept in that query line is the department name we picked

Comment: You can use a hidden field to store the department name we picked. And take the value from PHP. Now that I have updated my answer. Take a look at.